# Dismiss View Controller to Particular View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

My View Contollers 
Login -> Main Menu -> A -> B -> C -> D

**How do i dimiss all view controllers and go back to main menu**

For Logout from my view controllers I am doing the following which takes back to Login

```
func logout{

    self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
 }
```

Now what i am doing is this

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
     var viewControllerStack: [BaseViewController]!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    super.appDelegateBase.viewControllerStack.append(self)  
}

func go_To_MainMenu(){
    var countOfNumberOfViewCOntrollers = self.appDelegateBase.viewControllerStack.count 

        switch countOfNumberOfViewCOntrollers{

             self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            break;
        case 2:

            self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using segues?  If so, use an [unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your MainMenu VC always comes AFTER your Login VC, you could simply use the same method:

To MainMenu:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of presenting/dismissing you can use UINavigationController to push/pop view controllers. That way you can use UINavigationController's `popToViewController(_:animated:)` which can pop to any view controller in navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unwind Segue if MainMenu isn't your rootViewController. Look at this article, hope it will help.
[Unwind Segue with Swift](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

This works for me

```
var presentingViewController = PresentingViewController()
self.dismiss(animated: false) {
    presentingViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **unwind segue** instead of using RootViewController. 
Using unwind you can go back to any ViewController. DismissViewController always send the controller out from NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

self.view.window!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)